# Can I combine datasets in Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

I have 3 different datasets. Each pulls from the same datasource, but each has different filters in order to pull data as of a different points in time (12/31/15, 12/31/14, and 12/31/13). Each dataset contains the fields: enum, gender, and YearEnd (YearEnd I created using an expression). Can I combine the data from all 3 datasets into one table or matrix. My ultimate goal is to create a chart to show trends over time, but I can't figure out how to combine the data. Since I have different filters for each, I believe I have to have 3 datasets. I just can't figure out how to append them all into one. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet would be one combined dataset instead of three. Create a dataset that gets you the data for all three dates.

You can filter for the rows you want (date in ('12/31/15', '12/31/14', '12/31/15')) in either your SQL query/stored procedure or in your dataset options (right click dataset, properties, filters).

You can also filter at the table level (right click the outside border of the table, tablix properties).

You can break up your table to show different dates using column and row groups, as defined with group expressions, and use expressions as well to display custom headers (2015, 2014, 2013)

I haven't done much with charts in Report Builder, but from looking at it it looks like you can use filters and groups much the same way.